# Calling a video thru an ajax call

Tags: jquery

I am trying to load a flash video when the page is scrolled to a particular position thru ajax/jquery. Everything works and I get the expected data as below:

```
<div id="rr-brightcove" class="module vids rrmodule"><h3>Video</h3>

 <div class="module-body">

  <script src="http://admin.brightcove.com/js/BrightcoveExperiences.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <object id="myaolExperience" class="BrightcoveExperience">

    <param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF" />

    <param name="width" value="318" />

    <param name="height" value="295" />

    <param name="playerID" value=106573607001 />

    <param name="publisherID" value=1612833736/>

    <param name="isVid" value="true" />

    <param name="isUI" value="true" />

    <param name="autoStart" value="false" />

    <param name="@videoList" value=648729340001 />

    <param name="wmode" value="transparent">

  </object>

 </code>

</div>

</div>
```

However the problem is, when I append the response to a div on my page the script tag just disappers (stripped) and I can't play the video. It seems to only append the below without the script tag:

```
<div id="rr-brightcove" class="module vids rrmodule"><h3>Video</h3>

 <div class="module-body">

  <object id="myaolExperience" class="BrightcoveExperience">

    <param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF" />

    <param name="width" value="318" />

    <param name="height" value="295" />

    <param name="playerID" value=106573607001 />

    <param name="publisherID" value=1612833736/>

    <param name="isVid" value="true" />

    <param name="isUI" value="true" />

    <param name="autoStart" value="false" />

    <param name="@videoList" value=648729340001 />

    <param name="wmode" value="transparent">

  </object>

 </code>

</div>

</div>
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Thanks,
L

Answer (score 0):

This might be a security strip, to prevent hijacked pages from loading malicious scripts.
Try appending a script tag to the head with javascript instead of just putting it in the body together with a load of other HTML:

```
newScript = document.createElement('script');
newScript.type = 'text/javascript';
newScript.src = 'http://admin.brightcove.com/js/BrightcoveExperiences.js';
(document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]).appendChild(newScript);
```

Comment: Hey, tried your suggestion bu tno luck!. It requires the script to be stuck right above the embed code and it does not create the video otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative might be to load the script in the HEAD regardless, if it's not too big then it's not going to adversely affect your page load and it's only going to get executed if your script runs. Just a thought.

Comment: Hey, thanks. It requires the script to be stuck right above the embed code and it does not create the video otherwise.

Comment: You could try the jQuery getScript (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript) function.